# Is there a way to tell Svelte not to recycle a component?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I don't know if the title is super accurate, couldn't think of a better way to explain it.

Let's say we have a model:

```
let model = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Apple"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Orange"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Tomato"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Avocado"
  }
]
```

That we render like this:

```
{#each model as item}
    <Item {...item}></Item>
{/each}
```

In the `Item` component we print to console when the component gets mounted and destroyed:

```
<script>
    import {onMount, onDestroy} from 'svelte'
    
    export let id
    export let title

    onMount(() => {
        console.log('Mounted: ' + title)
    })
    onDestroy(() => {
        console.log('Destroyed: ' + title)
    })

</script>

<div id={id}>{title}</div>
```

We also have a button, which deletes the "Orange" element from the model:

```
function deleteOrange() {
    model.splice(1, 1)
    model = model // I don't know if this is the correct way to force an update
}
    
// ...

<input on:click={deleteOrange} type="button" value="Delete Orange">
```

When the button is pressed, the Orange component disappears from the DOM as it should, but the console says:

```
"Destroyed: Avocado"
```

Is there a way to tell Svelte to destroy the "Orange" component, instead of destroying "Avocado" and moving props around to match the model?

Svelte REPL:

https://svelte.dev/repl/f22b37cb88c449118ff76bb5a82c296e?version=3.48.0

Comment: you need to provide a [key](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks) to your `#each`. Also, don't mutate the array with splice, either `filter()` it or clone it before splicing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a `(key)` to your `each` loop:

```html
{#each model as item (item.id)}
    <Item {...item}></Item>
{/each}
```

This will ensure that DOM elements are properly tracked. As per the Svelte documentation:

> If a key expression is provided — which must uniquely identify each list item — Svelte will use it to diff the list when data changes, rather than adding or removing items at the end. The key can be any object, but strings and numbers are recommended since they allow identity to persist when the objects themselves change.

Comment: Thank you, must have missing that in the docs.

Comment: You're welcome! Slightly edited my answer, you will want to use either `(item.id)` or `(item.title)` as keys rather than simply `(item)` as scalars are better suited for that role than objects.